# matlab: displacement calculation for multiple trajectories

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, organization

I'm simulating diffusion of particles. Simulated coordinates are stored in matrix with a format format as follows:

```
data(:, 1) % overall track number
data(:, 2) % dataset number
data(:, 3) % individual track number (within dataset)
data(:, 4) % frame number
data(:, 5) % xcoordinate
data(:, 6) % ycoordinate
```

What I want to do, is to create another matrix storing squared displacements. Format will be like:

```
SD(:, 1)   % overall track number (like in data matrix)
SD(:, 2:n) % squared displacement between 1st and n-th frame
```

Note, that number of frames within every dataset is not equal. If amount of frames in each trajectory is less than n+1, lets keep it as NaN.

I'm calculating it using the worst and slowest method on Earth - by several for loops:

```
SD(:, 1) = data(:, 1);

for i=1:length(data(:, 1)) % I am taking each row
    for j=1:lagsToCalculate % then every timelag (or n as described above)
        if j<i  % check if enough data from the 1st point
            if data(i, 3) == data(i-j, 3) % and if it is still the same trajectory

                % calculate square displacement
                SD(i,j+1) = (data(i, 5)-data(i-j, 5))^2+(data(i, 6)-data(i-j, 6))^2;

            else

                SD(i, j+1) = NaN; % or set to NaN
            end
        else
            SD(i, j+1) = NaN;
        end
    end 
 end
```

I'm sure there is a billion times more effective method to do that, but I'm not very fluent in matlab (and programming at all) and couldn't come with any idea :) Can anyone suggest something reasonable? Maybe some data reorganization will help?
Thanks for every idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SD(:,1) = data(:,1) %as you already have
```

then

```
SD(2:n,1) = sum(diff(data(:,5:6)).^2,2)
```

I'm not sure how you initialise SD, but something like

```
SD = zeros(size(data))
```

might be appropriate.  I'll leave you to figure out the 2nd line above, as always with 'elegant' Matlab start at the innermost expression and build outwards.

Comment: thanks for answer. However I completely don't get your line: SD(2:n,1) = sum(diff(data(:,2:end)).^2,2). Coordinates are stored in data(:, 5) and data(:, 6). Another problem is that every new track is starting from different point (so you have to differentiate them or eliminate these nonsense displacements - in my code I'm using NaNs).

Comment: oh and sorry, should be SD(:, 2:n) not SD(2:n, 1), so in SD first column track# and then displacement for 1st, 2nd, 3rd....n lag. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, my code snippet used a test dataset I ran on Matlab.  Will edit soonmost.

Comment: Hmmm, my 'answer' is now downgraded to a hint until I have time to look at it again.

Comment: thanks :) Sample dataset can be downloaded here: [link](http://tinyurl.com/d6l6otn)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's maybe not the best solution, but maybe someone will find it helpful:

```
nData = size(data,1);
numberOfDeltaT = 10; % use whatever works for you
squaredDisplacement = zeros(nData, numberOfDeltaT);
squaredDisplacement(:, 1) = data(:, 1);

for track=1:max(data(:, 1))
    for dt = 1:numberOfDeltaT
        trackStart = find(data(:, 1)==track,1,  'first');
        trackEnd   = find(data(:, 1)==track,1,  'last');
        deltaCoords = data(trackStart+dt:trackEnd,5:6) - data(trackStart:trackEnd-dt,5:6);
        squaredDisplacement(trackStart+dt:trackEnd, dt+1) = sum(deltaCoords.^2,2); 
        squaredDisplacement(trackStart:trackStart+dt-1, dt+1) = NaN;
    end
end
```

(based on this answer: [Calculating mean-squared displacement (msd) with MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489048/calculating-mean-squared-displacement-msd-with-matlab))

Art.