# mean squared displacement from multiple trajectories

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of multiple particle trajectories that I would like to analyze separately The trajectory number is one of the columns of the matrix, so I am trying to sort based on that number. I am using some of the code from this answer: [MSD with matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489048/calculating-mean-squared-displacement-msd-with-matlab) (which was very helpful, thank you!) to calculate MSD, but I am having difficulty parsing out the individual trajectories. To explain in more detail what I am trying to do: I have trajectory outputs that are in matrix format, with one column for trajectory number, one column for x-position, one column for y-position, etc. I want to be able to take this information and calculate the mean-squared displacement for each trajectory. In order to do this, I have to create a way to distinguish data points based on trajectory number (which is listed in row 7 of `mymatrix`). This seems to be where I am having trouble. The important columns in this matrix are 1: x-position, 2: y-position and 7: trajectory number. So far I have

```
total_rows=size(mymatrix,1);
max_trajectory_number=mymatrix(total_rows,7);
nData=0;
msd=zeros(total_rows, 4)
for i=0:max_trajectory_number
    trajectornumber= mymatrix(i,7);
    if trajectorynumber.equals(i) 
    nData=nData+1;  %counts the number of instances of this trajectory number, which is the number of data points in the trajectory
    for dt = 1:nData
    deltaCoords = mymatrix(1+dt:end,1:2) - traj0mat(1:end-dt,1:2); %calculates time-averaged MSD based on y and y positions in colums 1 and 2 respectively
    squaredDisplacement = sum(deltaCoords.^2,2); %# dx^2+dy^2+dz^2
    msd(dt,1) = trajectorynumber; %trajectory number
    msd(dt,2) = mean(squaredDisplacement); %# average
    msd(dt,3) = std(squaredDisplacement); %# std
    msd(dt,4) = length(squaredDisplacement); %# n
    end

end
```

Unfortunately when I run this on `mymatrix`, the resulting msd matrix remains all zeros. I think this is likely due to an error in sorting based on the trajectory number. I do not get an error just not the results I was looking for

If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You appear to be missing an `end` for either your inner `for` loop or for your `if` statement.

Comment: And you have `trajectornumber= mymatrix(i,7);` - missing a `y`. Maybe just a transcription error, but could be causing `if trajectorynumber.equals(i) ` to always be 0 if `trajectorynumber` is never changed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to bundle all rows identified by the same trajectory number. I assume that they show up in chronological order as you continue down a column. Then  try something like

```
tnumbs = unique(mymatrix(:,7)); % identify unique trajectory numbers
for i=1:length(tnumbs) % loop through trajectories
    icurr = find(mymatrix(:,7)==tnumbs(i)); % find indices to entries for current trajectory

    % perform your averaging
    deltaCoords = mymatrix(icurr(1+dt:end),1:2) - traj0mat(icurr(1:end-dt),1:2); %calculates time-averaged MSD based on y and y positions in colums 1 and 2 respectively
    squaredDisplacement = sum(deltaCoords.^2,2); %# dx^2+dy^2+dz^2
    msd(i,1) = tnumbs(i); %trajectory number
    msd(i,2) = mean(squaredDisplacement); %# average
    msd(i,3) = std(squaredDisplacement); %# std
    msd(i,4) = length(squaredDisplacement); %# n
end
```